# text overflow in td html

Tags: html, css, html-table

the `p` doesn't wrap within `td`, see the demo below:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Grp2Q/

```
<td align="left" style="padding:0px; width:200px;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
 </td>

 <td style="padding-left:20px;max-width:100%;">
  <p>dfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgdfsdsdfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgsdfsdsdfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgsdfsdsdf</p>
 </td>
```

Comment: formatting is always a good gesture mate!!! :)

Comment: Because you have no space in your string

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com obviously he knows that, and that's why he is asking for solution

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com : no its not necessary to have a `space` to break the string!

Answer (score 4):

You need to break the text, to do that, make your `table` **fixed** `width` and than use `word-wrap` property with a value of `break-word`

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Grp2Q/4/)

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed; /* Make sure you use this as well */
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `word-break:break-all`

[**demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Grp2Q/6/)

```
<td style="padding-left:20px;max-width:100%;word-break:break-all;">
   <p>dfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgdfsdsdfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgsdfsdsdfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggdfgdfgsdfsdsdf</p>
</td>
```

Comment: @SurjithSM : yup...just link was not working..thanks for headsup!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a style like this to your paragraph:

```
.word_wrap {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/manojmcet/8AcFV/1/)**

**CSS**:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This answer is already there dude. Try upvoting instead of creating new

Comment: @NoobEditor I do, but sometimes, may be happen in sametime

Comment: @NoobEditor I didn't post an answer to this because I saw your post just before submitting.

Comment: I didn't see the previous  post , before i was submitting.sorry it won't happen in future..

Answer (score 0):

Please add on css
div table tr td{word-break: break-all;}